# Print out number in 64 bit nasm with c functions

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm, sasm

```
section .data
    radius dq 10
    pi dq 3.1416
    fmt db "Hello %d", 10, 0
    
section .text
    global main
    extern printf
    extern exit
    
main:
    mov rbp, rsp; for correct debugging
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, [radius]
    call printf
    
    push 0
    call exit
```

I am attempting to use printf in 64 bit assembly. All I want is to print out "Hello 6", but have 6 be put in using a %d in a format string. I have no clue why this isn't working. No matter what I do, I always get a segfault.

I have:
-Tried using windows with SASM, selected the 64 bit option. The program crashes and when I use the debugger, I receive the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff18973701 in ungetwc () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

-Tried creating a BRAND NEW Ubuntu VM, installed nasm, build-essential. Assembling returns no error, gcc returns no error, but when I run it, it always says "Segmentation Fault: core dumped."

-Tried using puts() instead of printf. This prints hello, as it should, but puts() doesn't allow me to do what I want.

-Assembled the program with:
nasm -f win64 -o your_program.obj your_program.asm (in windows)
nasm -f elf64 -o output_file.o input_file.asm (in ubuntu)

-Compiled the object file with:

```
gcc -o your_program.exe your_program.obj
gcc -o your_program.exe your_program.obj -static
gcc -o your_program.exe your_program.obj -no-pie
gcc -o your_program.exe your_program.obj -static -no-pie
```

-Tried to do the process on the command line in windows. I put nasm on my Path.

I've been working at this for 7 hours, and I've made no progress. The problem is the printf function. Whenever I use it, it doesn't work. I've tried everything. This assignment was due on monday and I can't even use printf.

Comment: Your stack is misaligned.  Also, `exit` takes its argument in `edi` (just like printf does), not frm the stack.  Windows has a different calling convention alltogether (your code follows the UNIX one).

Comment: @fuz I'm sorry, I don't know what the stack misalignment means. could you elaborate? I'm new to nasm.

Comment: In the amd64 SysV ABI (the calling convention for UNIX), the stack must be aligned to 16 bytes when you call a function.  If you don't pay attention to this, libc functions will crash due to alignment faults when using SSE instructions.  Your `printf` crash is typical in this regard.  You can fix this by e.g. pushing some register to at the beginning of your `main` function to restore alignment (when the C runtime calls `main`, it pushes the return address, misaligning the stack.  Another push restores alignment).

Comment: I have linked a duplicate with answers that check of some of the issues you have.  If that doesn't fix your problem, edit your question to add your new code with all the issues explained in answers to the other question fixed, and we can reopen your question.

Comment: Hi @fuz, I was wondering if you would mind helping me with something similar to this question. I have my nasm environment set up, but I can't figure out how to print out a float. I feel like I've looked everywhere on the internet, and I really need to get my assignment done. If I don't get it done, I fail my class. Could you maybe open a chatroom or something?

Comment: Please post a new question with the details about that.  You should be able to just use `printf` to print floats though.  If that doesn't work, show your code and I can have a look.